# React: How to align a component within a component?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am calling the Logo component from the Toolbar component. The image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Got.png)

I want the Logo to appear in the middle of the toolbar. Unfortunately, it is appearing in the extreme left. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Attaching the code:
Toolbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Toolbar.module.css';
import Logo from '../../Logo/Logo.js';

const toolbar = (props) =>(
    <div className ={styles.Toolbar}>
        <div>MENU</div>
        <Logo />
        <nav>
            ...
        </nav>
    </div>
);

export default toolbar;
```

Toolbar.module.css

```
.Toolbar{
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: #703B09;
    display: 'flex';
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 90;
}

.Toolbar nav{
    height:100%;
}
```

Logo.js

```
import React from 'react';
import burgerLogo from '../../assets/images/burger-logo.png';
import styles from './Logo.module.css';

const logo = (props) =>(
    <div className = {styles.Logo}>
        <img src = {burgerLogo} alt = "Burger Logo" />
    </div>
);

export default logo;
```

Logo.module.css

```
.Logo{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 8px;
    height:60%;
    width: 4%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.Logo img{
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `.Toolbar`

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the quotation marks in **display: 'flex'** (inside .Toolbar) are causing troubles. Just remove them and leave **display: flex**.